# How do you administer CUPS remotely using the web interface?

Tags: server, printing

I have an Ubuntu server in my apartment and I just got a printer, so it's time to share!

In the past I've used CUPS on my Desktop and I'd just point the browsers to localhost:631 to set things up. Can I used the web based admin tools remotely?

I've been playing with the `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` file and am currently at the point where I can direct a browser on my LAN to server-ip:631 but I'm getting the 403 Forbidden error.

If it's not possible or it's a bad idea for security reasons to allow remote administrator of CUPS, would it be possible to accomplish this using an SSH tunnel to the sever?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Mission achomplished! This [page helped me out a lot](http://thismightbehelpful.blogspot.com/2008/09/remote-access-to-cups-web-interface.html).

All I had to do was add "Allow all" to to the access to the server and the admin pages so that my configuration now looked like:

```
# Restrict access to the admin pages...
<Location /admin>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>

# Restrict access to configuration files...
<Location /admin/conf>
  AuthType Default
  Require user @SYSTEM
  Order allow,deny
</Location>
```

Now I just need to figure out to only allow those on my local network to access the admin pages and the configuration files :) (though it's probably not a big deal since I don't have port forwarding for 631 set up on the router?).

EDIT: To only allow a certain computer I could have done something like

```
<Location /admin>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from 10.10.10.5
</Location>
```

Or for the whole 10.10.10 subnet,

```
<Location /admin>
      Order allow, deny
      Allow from 10.10.10.*
</Location>
```

Answer (score 85):

I found this way to be simpler.

```
# cupsctl --remote-admin --remote-any --share-printers
```

It will update the `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` file and restart cups for you, saving a backup of the previous configuration in the same folder.

It's the similar to the method presented in the official CUPS [guide to printer sharing](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-2.0/sharing.html).
I found the options `--remote-admin` in `man cupsctl`.

Comment: It's sad to see many people browsing/referencing distribution-specific docs, blogs, and other sources rather than CUPS online help. :/

Comment: Always use the recommended way first! They made the software!

Comment: That's probably because they don't know what questions to ask; often, to use documentation, you either need to know exactly what you're looking for, or read the entire manual - not fun, and takes way too long. We also don't want to be CUPS experts, we just want to know how to flip one little switch.

Comment: i had to do `sudo service cups restart` after this, but then it worked! :) (debian 10 32bit)

Comment: no restart needed for me. Debian 8,9 and Arch

Comment: The tool removes original comments and newlines, making the file less readable. Shame...

Answer (score 42):

The way I normally achieve this is to tunnel over ssh via an arbitrary port:

```
ssh admin@10.36.8.43 -T -L 3631:localhost:631
```

Secure, and allows remote access. Won't solve all problems but useful for irregular access.

Comment: This tip is awesome: without changing anything on the cups configuration, you can securely administrate cups.

Comment: The `-T` option is not really needed; it will just prevent creation of a terminal session. Leave it out if you also need a terminal session for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add the following line to your CUPS configuration file (`/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`):

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:631           # existing loopback Listen
Listen /var/run/cups/cups.sock # existing socket Listen
// this two line 
// replace 192.168.10.250 with ur only ip
Listen 192.168.10.250:631      # Listen on the LAN interface, Port 631 (IPP)
Port 631  # Listen on port 631 on all interfaces
//
```

- Reference: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-cups

Answer (score 0):

Open up 2 terminals

Edit /etc/cups/cupsd.conf as root

```
sudo nano /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
```

Get the IP in the second terminal

```
hostname -I
```

Edit /etc/cups/cupsd.conf and have the server listen on the local ip, replace `192.168.1.111` with the above command

```
Listen localhost:631
Listen 192.168.1.111:631
```

Get the subnet mask in the second terminal

```
ip addr show | grep "inet " | grep -v "127.0.0.1" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d'/' -f1 | cut -d'.' -f1-3 | sed 's/$/.*/'
```

Edit /etc/cups/cupsd.conf and add in this replacing `192.168.1.*` with the subnet mask from above.

```
<Location />
  Order allow,deny
  Allow @LOCAL
  Allow from 192.168.1.*
</Location>

<Location /admin>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow @LOCAL
  Allow from 192.168.1.*
</Location>
```

Exit and save /etc/cups/cupsd.conf and then restart the cups server

```
sudo systemctl restart cups.service
```

Go to `http://192.168.1.111:631/` in your web browser (replace IP with the results from `hostname -I`) and setup your printer.