# How to install the printer installer on Ubuntu Server with Openbox?

Tags: server, printing, openbox

I want to install the printer (connected to the computer) using the printer installer which is founded in default installations of Ubuntu that come with some graphical part (Gnome, Unity etc).

There is a GUI tool which detects the printer and you can easily install it.

How can I install it on Ubuntu Server running Openbox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can install the `system-config-printer` like that found in Unity:

```
sudo apt-get install system-config-printer-gnome
```

Now you can run it from terminal:

```
system-config-printer
```

If you don't have cups installed, you can install it:

```
sudo apt-get install cups
```

Comment: Does this work for you?

Answer (score 5):

CUPS should be enough on its own (`sudo apt install cups`) and will be the base requirement of almost any printing system in Ubuntu.

CUPS has a web interface that does quite a lot more than the usual graphical frontends can. If you're on the server, just open `http://localhost:631/` in a browser.

[image]

Authentication (for printer administration) is for any user in the `lpadmin` group. You may need to add your user(s) to this group on Ubuntu Server though I imagine exactly the same goes for the other graphical clients too.

---

The web interface is restricted to local access by default so if it's a headless server and you only have remote access, you have at least a few options:

- Use port forwarding to mirror the remote port 631 locally (here as `localhost:63100`):

  ```
  ssh -L 63100:localhost:631 tank
  ```

  Then access `http://localhost:63100` in your local browser.
- [Tell CUPS to allow connections from any host](https://askubuntu.com/q/23936/449), then access `http://server_ip:631/` in your local browser. Make sure you are aware of the scurity implications of this first though.
- Use a command line browser over SSH. Not the prettiest but quick and functional.

  ```
  links http://localhost:631/
  ```

  [image]

  It's very similar to the interface in a graphical browser. Just compare it yourself.

Comment: Maybe a very dim question, but how do you visit this on a headless server?

Comment: @Arronical I've edited for that, though it seems unlikely it really applies to the OP here, given they're looking for graphical/OpenBox admins.

Comment: It was just for my own curiosity really, probably should have started a new question! Cheers for the info though.