# CUPS Web GUI on remote server

Tags: 14.04, networking, printing, webapps

I am trying to setup web access to the CUPS on my remote server Ubuntu 14.04

It should be very easily:

```
sudo apt-get install cups 

# instead of manualy change /etc/cups/cupsd.conf 
sudo cupsctl --remote-admin  # and looks OK
sudo service cups restart
```

As I understand now I should be able to acces the CUPS web GUI from IP address

```
server-ip:631 or server-ip:631/admin  (or same with https://)
```

I don't get even "access denied" page. After some time browser show  "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

Should I install some kind of web server for this? Or anything else?

edit:

```
$ netstat -antp|grep 631
tcp    0     0 0.0.0.0:631       0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN   13011/cupsd     
tcp6   0     0 :::631            :::*            LISTEN   13011/cupsd     


$ iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Nov  3 22:12:45 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [35932464:3745849365]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [32176449:4015002291]
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Nov  3 22:12:45 2016
```

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/a/532123/602680) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Firewalls? `netstat -antp|grep 631`  and  `iptables-save`...

Comment: @RostislavKandilarov He's trying to access his **remote** server's **local** IP address. He's not on the same network, nor is CUPS hosting the server on the server's external IP. The link that I referenced is a solution to this.

Comment: Actually I checked that link and execute cupsctl --remote-admin After that  cupsd.conf is configured well...

Comment: @tasmaniski  So is it working or did nothing change?

Comment: @tasmaniski Just to clarify, are you on the same network as the server? Also, are you using the server's internal or external IP address when trying to connect with your browser?

Comment: Not working...  pls. see my edit  cc @RostislavKandilarov

Comment: No, I am not on the same network and I am using the server public IP.  I am running web app with nginx on same server and that works on that public IP.

Comment: You would need to forward the appropriate port through the router to the target system.

Comment: `iptables-save` ?

Comment: @ElderGeek Sorry to ask, but  Are you sure?  I am on home laptop and CUPS is installed on remote server in Germany (different country). So I just want to access to web admin through public IP.

Comment: @tasmaniski Yes, you would need to forward the 631 port to be accessible outside of the local network of the server.

Comment: That would be the common approach. However I suppose you could try tunneling over SSH as mentioned here:http://askubuntu.com/questions/23936/how-do-you-administer-cups-remotely-using-the-web-interface/164971#164971

Comment: As suggested by Elder Geek and Owen Hines, can you answer also if there is any router between Internet and your print server? `/sbin/ifconfig` ?